Connect Dagster to GCP CloudSQL
I'm currently using Airflow to run a GCP CloudSQL<>GCS<>BigQuery ETL but I'm interested in porting this to Dagster. Airflow has the MsSqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator but Dagster doesn't have a similar integration, how would I get started connecting to CloudSQL from within Dagster?
